# Using HTML Color code in JAVA Font color

Tags: java, graphics2d

Is there any way to use HTML hash color code for Font?

I mean `#FFFFFF` to use it for

`g2d.setColor(Color.white);`

Comment: String color = "FFFFFF"; g2d.setColor(Color.decode("0x" + color));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try

```
int intValue = Integer.parseInt( "FFFFFF",16);
Color aColor = new Color( intValue );
```

EDIT:

To get color by name, you could use reflection,

```
Color aColor   = (Color) Color.class.getField("white").get(null);
```

EDIT 2:

from @eee

```
Color aColor = Color.decode("#FFFFFF");
```

or

```
Color aColor = Color.decode("0xFFFFFF");
```

Comment: damn, missed you by 40 seconds.

Comment: Is  there any way if its passed as string For Example "White" , "Black" etc ?

Comment: @Andrew thanks. It doesn't seem to work for named colors like "white" but for hex, it looks like you'll have to specify "0x" or "#".

Comment: @Bala 'It doesn't seem to work for named colors like "white"'.  I'm glad.  The color names are a bit limiting, in any case.

Comment: `The constructor Color(String) is undefined`... It's `Color.decode(String)` as eee said.

Answer (score 4):

```
g2d.setColor( new Color( Integer.parseInt( "FFFFFF", 16 ) ) );
```